# Can nslookup but not ping after OpenSuse Tumbleweed update

Tags: wifi, dns, opensuse

Following the 02/09 Tumbleweed update my DNS seems to be broken.

My wifi icon in top right has a question mark, `ping google.com` returns `Name or service not known`, but `nslookup google.com` correctly returns the IP address. If I go to Google's IP address in Firefox I get the message `We can't connect to the server at www.google.com.` so it is being resolved somehow.

I can ping `8.8.8.8`.

I've tried all the other answers I can see for related issues but none have worked for me. My `resolv.conf` is:

```
search MYDOMAIN
nameserver IP1
nameserver IP2
```

where IP1 & 2 are my companies addresses.

I've tried changing `nsswitch.conf` and reduced the `hosts` line to `files dns` (removing the mdns4 bit).

If I force Google's DNS then it still doesn't work, i.e. if I try `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` it fails, and if I go into NetworkManager and add `8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4` to DNS in IPv4 settings for my Wifi then it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do not use `ping` to troubleshoot DNS issues. The correct tool for that is `dig`, which is superiot to `nslookup`. By default it will use nameservers defined in `/etc/resolv.conf` so the first step is making sure you can contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by adding `dns=dnsmasq` under `[main]` in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem after update from Leap 15.0 to Leap 15.1: `nslookup` worked but `ping` or anything else that required dns resolution didn't. I did all the standard checks (`resolv.conf`, `nsswitch.conf`, `/etc/sysconfig/network/config`) and these were in order. Switching from `wicked` to `NetworkManager` and enabling `dnsmasq` as above solved my issue initially.

I dug a little deeper and found a tip here that it may be related to issues in apparmor configuration: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/536437-DNS-problem-after-upgrade-from-15-0?p=2906092#post2906092

Similarly to that thread on my system that there was an updated configuration in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/nameservice.rpmnew` which allowed access to additional directories used by `nscd`. Once I copied over this new config file and cleared the apparmor cache as described in that post, `wicked` started working and I could revert my network manager config back to the original version, without needing to use `dnsmasq`.

Comment: Exactly the same thing here after the update from 15.0 to 15.1.